# Selenium Object of Type WebElement has no len()

Tags: python, selenium, variables, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to log into Facebook Marketplace from Selenium. The email address is populating as expected. The password field is not being recognized.

The error:

> File "C:\Users\jsmith\fb.py", line 18, in 
> password.send_keys(password)
> TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

username = 'myemail'
password = 'mypassword'
#OpenBrowser
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://facebook.com/")

#Logging
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
#facebook username input
email.send_keys(username)
#facebook password input
password.send_keys(password)
```

I have tried using `find_element_by_name()` and `find_element_by_id()` (and the plural of both) in addition to the xpath above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 variables named password, so when you try to send you password string to input, it won't work

Answer (score 3):

In your code block the variable `password` initially was referring to the string value of **mypassword**. Moving forward, `password` was reinitialized as a WebElement. Hence when you pass the variable `password` within `send_keys(password)` it referred to an WebElement. Hence you see the error:

```
password.send_keys(password) TypeError: object of type 'WebElement' has no len()
```

---

### Solution

Change the variable name of the *Password* field from `password` to `pass` as follows:

```
password = 'mypassword'
# other lines of code
pass = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="pass"]')
#facebook password input
pass.send_keys(password)
```